# Dynamic values for MultiValue in Watchkit Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm having trouble understanding how I can have dynamic data fed into a `MultiValue` attribute inside the `Root.plist` file of a `Settings-Watch.bundle`.

When fetching some REST API I would like to retrieve some map (dictionary) and set that data as the list of choice in my Watch Settings Bundle so that the user can select a specific value from it inside the Apple Watch application on the iPhone/iPad.

I tried like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *watchPrefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.foo"];
// foo and titles are NSArray* of NSString.
// I also tried by giving it a NSDictionary* whose keys are what's in foo and values reflecting bar
[watchPrefs registerDefaults:@{@"preferedAccount": @{@"Values": foo, @"Titles": bar}}];
[watchPrefs synchronize];
```

But even when I close the app these data are not shown in the Watch application > My application.

I configured the `preferedAccount` as a MultiValue inside the `Root.plist` file.

It must be dynamic in that case because the data reflects the logged user and so cannot be known in advance.

Is it even possible to display dynamic data there ?

Thanks